# PHP preg_replace() - comma separated values?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a huge string and somewhere in it is a part that goes "letters,numbers,numbers" and I'm trying to find that part and update the two numbers with preg_replace(). I can't figure out the regex. Here's what I have:

```
preg_replace('/'.$slug.',{0-9},{0-9}/', $slug.','.$num1.','.$num2, $mystring);
```

But it doesn't work. I'm a regex noobie, can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this:

```
preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($slug).',\d+,\d+/', $slug.','.$num1.','.$num2, $mystring);
```

Comment: While this is a good start, I believe there is more to the OP's question.

Comment: looks like what I want, but gives me "Unknown modifier '/'". Tried removing the slashes but no dice?

Comment: use preg_quote($slug), you can use another solution from Nathanael Shermett

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/('.$slug.'),([0-9]*),([0-9]*)/', '$1,'.$num1.','.$num2, $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error you mentioned you got based on the other example, it appears that `$slug` may be interfering with the regular expression. `preg_quote()` helps keep this from happening, escaping reserved characters.

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($slug) . ',{0-9},{0-9}/', "$slug,$num1,$num2", $mystring);
```

Comment: edit: answered my own question, preg_quote need a second '/' parameter!